# References for the effect of binning methods?

Tags: binning

There are two main ways to bin a numerical signal into discrete categorical values:

- Quintile Binning: Each Bin will have the same size
- Histogram Binning: A normal distribution will be used to bin the signal

When should I use one or the other?

Comment: Quintile here implies precisely 5 bins. The term you want is quantile. However, there is a bigger confusion over histogram binning, which in general doesn't use a normal distribution in any way. What is customary for histogram binning is to use bins of equal width unless there is good reason to do otherwise. As for the question, what are your goals?